# HTML5 Video Won't Play on Android Devices, But Plays on All Browsers and iPhone

Tags: android, html, video, samsung-mobile, galaxy

I've been trying to solve this issue for days now, and I've Googled and researched as much as I can, but no answer has solved the problem yet.

I have put a video on a web page I'm working on using the HTML5 video tag. It works in all the desktop browsers I've tried (Firefox, Chrome, IE) and it has worked on 2 iPhones I've tried (iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s), but I can't get it to play for the life of me on my android devices (Samsung Galaxy S5 and Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0). The video player shows up on the page and allows me to press the Play button, but when I do it just sits for a minute or 2 and then pops up with a message saying "Sorry, unable to play video."

I have 3 different file types for the video (4 technically if you count mp4 and m4v as two different types) and they are mp4, webm, and ogg. The mp4 is encoded with H.264. I've tried converting them several times with a converter that specifies "types for specific devices, etc" just to see if I could get any different conversions to work.

This is the code I am using:

```
<video width="480" height="270" controls>
   <source src="../pages/videos/video001.mp4">
   <source src="../pages/videos/video001.m4v" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="../pages/videos/video001.webm" type="video/webm">
   <source src="../pages/videos/video001.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I've tried different aspect ratios and sizes. I've done the whole "turn your device off then back on," I've cleared out my cache and cookies data on my browser (trying to access via Chrome), and I've also tried to play it on the Samsung Galaxy native browser vs. chrome (the name is escaping me at the moment) and it didn't work on there either.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. This is driving me insane!

Comment: Quick question - have you tried using Firefox for Android or Dolphin browser? If it works in at least one of those, then we might have a starting point. And can you successfully play any HTML5 videos on, say, youtube's desktop site?

Comment: Yes, I tried using Firefox. I don't know what Dolphin browser is though? I've tried Firefox, Chrome, and the native browser all for Android.

Comment: I know your post is an old one, but I've been head banging over this same issue for days. It seems as though Android webview doesn't play nicely with the html5 video tag. I have a cordova web app that has been published successfully on iPhone and for Android Lollipop 5.1.1, but the videos won't play on Marshmallow 6.0.1. I've tried many solutions and wonder if you have found the fix for this issue. Thanks.